# any tip on how to convert the following code to reacts from vanilla Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i intend to convert this vanilla javaScript code to react.
below are the html and javaScripts codes...

**HTML**

```
<div class="middle">
                <img src="images/vr-iootz.jpg" draggable="false"/>
            </div>



<div class="scroller scroller-middle">
                <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:rgb(24,24,62)"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:rgb(24,24,62)"/></svg>
            </div>
```

**Vanilla Js Code**

```
scrollerMiddle.addEventListener('mousedown',function(){
  active = "middle";
  scrollerMiddle.classList.add('scrolling');
});
```

of course i knew that it can be like this as shown below using reacts..

```
<div className="scroller mouseDown={ () => {
    active = "middle"}

}">


  <svg
    className="scroller__thumb"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="100"
    height="100"
    viewBox="0 0 100 100"
  >
    <polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" fill="rgb(24,24,62)" />
    <polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" fill="rgb(24,24,62)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

but how about these code  **scrollerMiddle** too, since using the object creation has been bypass by the new react event handler features as shown above i.e **mouseDown={}** ....

so how can i includes these...

```
scrollerMiddle.classList.add('scrolling');
```

having difficulty in vanilla to react code conversion..

the codes works as intended in vanilla js

Answer (score 0):

React has already build-in features, such as event listeners for your case `onMouseDown` which you set on the element you want.

```
<div className="scroller-middle" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>
```

In order to know which element you want to apply the className, we use `useRef`: https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef

```
import { useRef } from "react";
.
.
.
const divRef = useRef(null);
.
.
.
<div ref={divRef} className="scroller-middle" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>
```

Now, everytime onMouseDown event listener is called, we add `scrolling` class name to the element.

```
const handleMouseDown = () => {
   divRef.current.classList.add("scrolling");
};
```

We also need to make sure, to put everything inside a fragment `<> </>`.

Same for some `polygon` styling, we use `fill` prop to put there the colors we want.

```
<polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" fill="rgb(24,24,62)" />
<polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" fill="rgb(24,24,62)" />
```

Full code:

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const divRef = useRef(null);

  const handleMouseDown = () => {
    divRef.current.classList.add("scrolling");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="middle">
        <img src="images/vr-iootz.jpg" draggable="false" alt="/" />
      </div>

      <div
        ref={divRef}
        className="scroller-middle"
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      >
        <svg
          className="scroller__thumb"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="100"
          height="100"
          viewBox="0 0 100 100"
        >
          <polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" fill="rgb(24,24,62)" />
          <polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" fill="rgb(24,24,62)" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess i can always create multiple sets of **ref={divRef}** like this for multiple objects...

many thanks

Comment: one more thing..

how about these two,


**document.body.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
  active = false;
  scrollerMiddle.classList.remove('scrolling');
});**


and this,


**document.querySelector('.wrapper').getBoundingClientRect().left;
  scrollIt(x);
});**

 then I am good.

thanks

Comment: Well, you add the `onMouseUp` event to the div, eg: `<div onMouseup={myFunctionName}>My div</div>` and it will be called everytime when you mouse up and you can set there the state to false or true, you should use `useState` btw. For `getBoundingClientRect`, if you need some of the scroll left or width or anything, you can use it on a `useRef`, sure, something like `myDivRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().scrollLeft` and it will get how much you scrolled from the left of that specific div/scroll bar. For other questions, open a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks. i have been able to get it solve to 95 %.